# JAVA object escape about String

Tags: java, string, object, escaping

I recently research about object escape in java and confused about following code,

```
public static StringBuffer newStringBuffer(String s1, String s2) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(s1);
    sb.append(s2);
    return sb;
}
```

I know the "sb" escape from that method,but i am not understand,why that code can be optimize like following,

```
public static String newStringBuffer(String s1, String s2) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(s1);
    sb.append(s2);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

sb.toString() can not be escape? 
Thanks.

Comment: `String` is immutable, so it's better to return one of those if that's all you need, since the invoking code can be absolutely sure it can't cause a side effect by modifying the returned value.

Comment: Your code really can't be changed like that, because then it's not doing its job of `newStringBuffer`, is it?

Comment: That is not an optimization.  
You do the second way when you need to get a String from the client side and the first way when you need to get the String Builder   
Besides, that is not an escape but a return.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking about. Can you clarify what you mean by "escape" (it probably doesn't mean thing described in tag you used).

Comment: @Pshemo I believe op is referring return as escape.

Comment: Who can optimize the code? The JIT? You?

Comment: @Goion That is also my assumption but it is still *assumption*.

Comment: @Pshemo The return type is the only thing that differs in the two codes. So what else ?

Comment: "Escape" means the object can be visible outside the method call. If the compiler finds during escape analysis that the object is not visible outside the method call, it can perform optimizations, such as not putting the local object on the heap, which can reduce the need for garbage collection.

Comment: @AndyThomas - thanks for the explanation. So the stringbuilder escapes from the method when you return it, and doesn't escape when you don't return it.  Uh, am I missing something?

Comment: @another-dave - See fuller answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I was needlessly sarcastic. Your answer was perfectly understandable. What I wasn't sure about was why the OP had a problem; it's clear that the SB is not getting returned in the 2nd case, so it cannot escape.

Answer (score 0):

"Escape" means the object can be visible outside the method call. If the compiler finds during escape analysis that the object is not visible outside the method call, it can perform optimizations, such as not putting the local object on the heap, which can reduce the need for garbage collection.

Typically when you're using a StringBuffer, at some point you will ask it for a String. If the method returns a String rather than the StringBuffer, then **one less object might be put on the heap**.

By the way, another optimization is to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. The former discards the thread-safety provided by the latter, for greater speed. Many string concatenations are performed on a single thread, making the thread-safety unnecessary.